# Android: SimpleCursorAdapter with ListView - Put multiple fields from DB into TextView

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

I'm new to Android development, so I'm not even sure whether this is the best way to do it or not. So if you got another approach for my problem feel free to give ma advice.

My plan is pretty basic. I've got a table which contains player, this table contains, besides other fields, first- and lastnames.

I want to display all player in on ListView. The SimpleCursorAdapter I'm using allows me to map one Databasefield to one Textview. But I want to display the first- and lastname in one Textview. How do I do that?

Here's the code I got:

```
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{
        DatabaseLayout.Player.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,
        DatabaseLayout.Player.COLUMN_LASTNAME
    };

    int[] toViewIds = new int[]{
        R.id.txt_item_playerName,
        R.id.txt_item_playerLastName
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_lv_player, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds);

    ListView lvPlayer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPlayer);
    lvPlayer.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Thanks in advance,
Mazen

Comment: or (more advanced  solution) use a CursorWrapper

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement your own subclass of array adapter. Try this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html